# Making Kinect and Processing work on Mac.

Tags: macos, kinect, processing

I am trying to run some of the examples with running Kinect and Processing together

http://www.shiffman.net/p5/kinect/

I have installed everything in the directions. However, when I run the processing code, it says "Kinect not found". I have done nothing except for:
1. install processing
2. install relevant libraries
3. connect kinect to computer

I have a feeling I am missing something obvious here. I am just confused because this particular library only works on Macs, but the Kinect generally works on Windows. Any guidance towards making my Mac recognize there is a kinect connected to it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I can't help cause i never tried Kinect, but you might ask this in processing [forum](http://forum.processing.org). There are some experienced users of kinect there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Kinect on OSX, Windows or Linux depending on the drivers/SDK (e.g. Kinect for Windows will only run on Windows 7 and up, but OpenKinect/libreenect or OpenNI will run on the above mentioned).

I'm not sure if you need to install the libusb-devel driver or not, but you should give that a go using [MacPorts](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#MacPorts) for example:

```
sudo port install git-core
 sudo port install libtool
 sudo port install libusb-devel
```

Also the Processing OpenKinect wrapper is a bit limited. You can't get accelerometer data for example. Other than the depth,RGB,IR streams with OpenNI also supplies, motor control is the only extra feature. On the other hand OpenNI also comes with hand tracking, gestures, skeleton and scene detection, etc. I recommend giving [SimpleOpenNI](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/wiki/Installation) a go.

[image: simpleopenni 1]
[image: simpleopenni 2]